# Why no extra downvote with spam flag any more?

Tags: discussion, bug, flagging, spam, down-votes

When I flag an answer as spam, it simply flags it up and doesn't add an extra downvote, previously though I would downvote the question/answer, and then upon the spam flag the system would give it another downvote, was this a bug which has been fixed? Something which has been decided against? Or a bug in itself that it no longer works that way?

Comment: I flagged this post as spam, and it got a downvote.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this couldn't be reproduced.

Comment: Hold on though, you mean that you 1) first downvoted 2) then flagged as spam and upon this an additional downvote wasn't cast, differently from what it used to happen?

Comment: In any case you shouldn't downvote spam answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193917/302251

Comment: @kos: In the past, I would cast a downvote on a question, and then when I flagged the post as spam an additional downvote would be cast (so it allowed me to cast two downvotes), but this no longer happens so I am wondering why? Is this a bug which has been fixed? Or is it a bug that it doesn't work any more? I have not tried on Meta though, so I don't know how it works here...

Comment: @kos: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Ok, then I missunderstood the question (and @muru as well I believe). Sorry about that, I'm retracting my close vote.

Comment: It seems to be that this is actually happening, and it is casting the additional downvote except I have to refresh the page to see it for some reason... So not a bug SE's end after all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a developer at Stack Exchange, but if I would be, that's how I would do it:

#### Definitely, positively do not allow Pesky Panda's to downvote *and* spam.

## ;-)

I'm now going to downvote and then flag your question as spam and get back to you!

**-2** was the result, so I hoped they would have disallowed this feature just for you, **but [what's really happening is that you need to refresh the page to see what's happening](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26435182#26435182)**